# Data lost Sonarqube migration 6.6 to 6.7.1

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to upgrade sonarqube from version 6.6 to LTS version 6.7.1. 
I noticed post migration all the projects configured are lost. 
Wondering if anyone has encountered this before or there is any solution to it.

Comment: did you do it the recommended way? Starting first without anything, and configuring, and adding the data source later? than you maybe need to delete the data/es folder and start reindex for Elastic search again